# How to compile Simple C program in QNX

Tags: qnx

I am trying to compile simple C program using QNX as shown below.

conftest.c

```
int main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

compiling with option:

`qcc conftest.c -V4.7.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le_cpp`

compiler throw error like below

```
cc: ignoring unknown option '"-D__GNUC__'
cc: ignoring unknown option '"-D__GNUC__'
cc: ignoring unknown option '   --dynamic-linker /usr/lib/ldqnx.so.2 --sysroot'
cc: ignoring unknown option '   --hash-style'
cc: ignoring unknown option '%(fmudflap: --wrap'
cc: ignoring unknown option '"-D__GNUC__'
cc: ignoring unknown option '"-D__GNUC__'
cc: ignoring unknown option '   --dynamic-linker /usr/lib/ldqnx.so.2 --sysroot'
cc: ignoring unknown option '   --hash-style'
cc: ignoring unknown option '%(fmudflap: --wrap'
 failed: No such file or directoryys-qnx-660-all/bin/sys/qnx/host/linux/x86/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi/4.7.3/
 failed: No such file or directoryys-qnx-660-all/bin/sys/qnx/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-as
 error 1e//Desktop/sys-qnx-660-all/bin/sys/qnx/host/linux/x86/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi/4.7.3/
 error 1e/Desktop/sys-qnx-660-all/bin/sys/qnx/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-as
```

How to I compile it?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can compile through QNX IDE . Remember Do not change the default template signature .

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


  return 0;    
}
```

Right click on the project & **First** `Clean project` then `Build project` . If still it do not compile then let me know .

Also, this [URL](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/momentics/quickstart/about.html#Compiling) May help you .